# Inserting into MySQL table from Eclipse with html form values- Wrong syntax error

Tags: java, html, mysql, database

I am trying to insert values that are received from an html form. Everything seems to be working until I try and insert the values and I am receiving a wrong syntax error, but I have tried changing it to no avail. Here is my code:

The connection is being established, so I am not sure whats wrong.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.UUID;

public abstract class Log {
    private String uuid;
    private String title;
    private String content;
    private String createTimestamp;
    
  
    
    
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
       public String getUUID() {
            return uuid;
        }

        public void setUUID(String uuid) {  
            this.uuid = uuid;
        }

        public String getContent() {
            return content;
        }

        public void setContent(String content) {
            this.content = content;
        }

        public String getCreateTimestamp() {
            return createTimestamp;
        }

        public void setCreateTimestamp(String createTimestamp) {
            this.createTimestamp=createTimestamp;
            
        }
}

    package com.algonquin.loggy.servlets;
    
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.UUID;
    
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    
    import com.algonquin.loggy.beans.Log;
    import com.algonquin.loggy.beans.TextLog;
    import com.algonquin.loggy.dao.ApplicationDao;
    import com.algonquin.loggy.dao.DBConnection;
    
    /**
     * Servlet implementation class LogsServlet
     */
    @WebServlet("/LogsServlet" )
    public class LogsServlet extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
         */
        public LogsServlet() {
            super();
        }
    
        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
         *      response)
         */
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            String htmlResponse = "<html><head><link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"style.css\"><title>Loggy Servlet Form</title></head>"
                    + "<body><form id=\"logForm\" action=\"LogsServlet\" method=\"post\" >\n"
                    + "        <h3>Create A New Log!</h3>\n"
                    + "       \n"
                    + "        <label id=\"logTitleLabel\" for=\"title\">Title :</label>\n"
                    + "        <br>\n"
                    + "        <input type=\"text\" id=\"logTitle\" name=\"title\" maxLength=\"60\">\n"
                    + "        <br>\n"
                    
                    + "        <label id=\"logContentLabel\" for=\"content\">Content :</label>\n"
                    + "        <br>\n"
                    + "        <input type=\"text\" id=\"logContent\" name=\"content\">\n"
                    + "        <br>\n"
                    + "        <button type=\"submit\" id=\"submitLog\">Submit Log</button>\n"
                    + "        \n"
                    + "        </form></body></html>";;
            PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
            writer.write(htmlResponse);
        }
    
    
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException{
        
        String title = request.getParameter("title");
        String description = request.getParameter("description");
        String content = request.getParameter("content");
        String output;
        String uuid =UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        String createTimestamp=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new java.util.Date());
        //ArrayList<Log> logsList = new ArrayList<Log>();
        Log log= new TextLog();
        
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        try {
            
            log.setTitle(title);
            log.setContent(content);
            log.setCreateTimestamp(createTimestamp);
            log.setUUID(uuid);
            
            //logsList.add(log);
            
            output="<html><body><h3>Log successfully created</h3></body></html>";
            writer.write(output);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                output="<html><body><h3>Log could not be created</h3></body></html>";
                writer.write(output);
            }
        
                
        ApplicationDao dao = new ApplicationDao();
        String indexForm = "<html><head><link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"style.css\"><title>Loggy Servlet Form</title></head>"
                + "<body><form id=\"logForm\" action=\"LogsServlet\" method=\"post\" >\n"
                + "        <h3>Create A New Log!</h3>\n"
                + "       \n"
                + "        <label id=\"logTitleLabel\" for=\"title\">Title :</label>\n"
                + "        <br>\n"
                + "        <input type=\"text\" id=\"logTitle\" name=\"title\" maxLength=\"60\">\n"
                + "        <br>\n"
            
                + "        <label id=\"logContentLabel\" for=\"content\">Content :</label>\n"
                + "        <br>\n"
                + "        <input type=\"text\" id=\"logContent\" name=\"content\">\n"
                + "        <br>\n"
                + "        <button type=\"submit\" id=\"submitLog\">Submit Log</button>\n"
                + "        \n"
                + "        </form></body></html>";
        
        writer.write(indexForm);
        
        String insertQuery ="INSERT INTO `logs`(`uuid`, `title`, `content`, `createTimestamp`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
        Connection connection =DBConnection.getConnectionToDatabase();
        
        
        java.sql.PreparedStatement statement;
        try {
            statement = connection.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
            statement.setString(1,log.getUUID());
            statement.setString(2,log.getTitle());
            statement.setString(3,log.getContent());
            statement.setString(4,log.getCreateTimestamp());
            
            statement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    
    public class DBConnection {
    
        // Database Schema
        // CREATE DATABASE loggy DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
        // CREATE TABLE logs (uuid CHAR(40) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, title CHAR(128),
        // content TEXT, createTimestamp Date);
    
         private static final String dbUser = "user";
            private static final String dbPassword = "password";
            private static Connection connection = null;
            
    
            public static Connection getConnectionToDatabase() {
                
    
                try {
    
                    // load the driver class
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    System.out.println("MySQL JDBC Driver Registered!");
    
                    // get hold of the DriverManager
                    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/loggy",dbUser,dbPassword);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    System.out.println("Where is your MySQL JDBC Driver?");
                    e.printStackTrace();
    
                }
    
                catch (SQLException e) {
                    System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
                    e.printStackTrace();
    
                }
    
                if (connection != null) {
                    System.out.println("Connection made to DB!");
                }
                return connection;
                
            }
            
    
              
        }
    
    package com.algonquin.loggy.dao;
    
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import java.sql.Timestamp;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    
    import com.algonquin.loggy.beans.Log;
    import com.algonquin.loggy.beans.TextLog;
    import com.algonquin.loggy.services.ApplicationService;
    
    public class ApplicationDao implements ApplicationService {
    
    
            public List<Log> listLogs() {
                    
                Log log = null;
                List<Log> logs = new ArrayList<>();
                
                try{
                    Connection connection = DBConnection.getConnectionToDatabase();
                    
                    String sql = "select * from logs";
                    
                    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                    
                    ResultSet set = statement.executeQuery(sql);
                    
                    while(set.next()){
                        
                        String title = set.getString("title");
                        String content =set.getString("content");
                        String createTimestamp =set.getString("createTimestamp");
                        String uuid = set.getString("uuid");
                        
                        
                        Log log1 =new TextLog();
                        log1.setTitle(title);
                        log1.setContent(content);
                        log1.setCreateTimestamp(createTimestamp);
                        log1.setUUID(uuid);
                
                        logs.add(log1);
                        
                    }
    
                }
                catch(SQLException exception){
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
                return logs;
    
                }
        }

 
ERROR MESSAGE:

  MySQL JDBC Driver Registered!
Connection made to DB!
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''logs' values('25de3284-4fea-4851-9215-13c51bb333cd','Log 101','this is a tes...' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:916)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1061)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1009)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1320)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:994)
    at com.algonquin.loggy.servlets.LogsServlet.doPost(LogsServlet.java:127)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Also, I have to display the objects in an html list that each item to be deleted, if there is any advice on that, that would be appreciated as well!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error is:

> check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''logs' values

This looks like you're using single-quotes (`'`) to delimit the table name. Single-quotes in SQL are used for string delimiters, not identifier delimiters.

This is strange, because in your code you're clearly using back-ticks:

```
String insertQuery ="INSERT INTO `logs`(`uuid`, `title`, `content`, `createTimestamp`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
```

I'm forced to conclude that the error is not coming from the code you showed in your question. I suggest you search for other code that may be doing the INSERT differently.

Comment: The submitted code is the entire program that's why I'm super confused!

Comment: Right, but one possible explanation is that the code you're looking at is not the code that's running. For example, maybe because you haven't deployed that code, or else some different compiled copy of the class is found on your CLASSPATH ahead of the code you show. I've made both of these types of mistakes, and I've observed many other developers make those mistakes too.

Comment: Thank you so much! that's exactly what is was! I had imported the same war file before and had not deleted it!

Comment: It was a hunch, but I'm glad it led you to the issue! Best wishes.